Why does the US believe that Pakistan's missile program is now directed against it?
Pakistan's missile program is 'emerging threat', top US official says

If those trends continue, Finer said, "Pakistan will have the capability to strike targets well beyond South Asia, including in the United States."
The number of nuclear-armed states with missiles that can reach the U.S. homeland "is very small and they tend to be adversarial," he continued, naming Russia, North Korea and China.
"So, candidly, it's hard for us to see Pakistan's actions as anything other than an emerging threat to the United States," Finer said.

Why does the USA think that a Pakistani-made long-range ballistic missile will inevitably go against US interests?
I mean, where does this preconceived notion come from?

The quote doesn't make that claim. It says "an emerging threat".  There is nothing at all about "inevitably strike US installations"

I think you are bringing your preconceived notions to bear

@JamesK, "So, candidly, it's hard for us to see Pakistan's actions as anything other than an emerging threat to the United States," Finer said. --- what does this mean, then?

It means what it says.  "Pakistan may become a threat" doesn't mean "Pakistan will inevitably strike US interests".  And yes a nuclear armed Pakistan may be a threat. The leaders of Pakistan are unstable with multiple rounds of elected leaders being deposed. There are Islamist groups active, it has a long-term quarrel with its neigbour India.  It is not a natural ally of the USA, and so if it develops the ability to deliver a nuclear weapon to the USA, it may emerge as a threat.

@JamesK, The leaders of Pakistan are unstable with multiple rounds of elected leaders being deposed. --- Pakistan is not run by elected leaders. It is run by the military. You know that and I also know that.

@JamesK, ... it has a long-term quarrel with its neighbor India. --- and why is the USA so sensitive and protective of the security of India? Given that India intelligence is active in assassinating US and Canadian citizens?

@JamesK, It is not a natural ally of the USA, ... --- why does the USA expect that only natural allies would possess long-range missiles and others wouldn't?

I don't see the US as being particularly protective of India.  It is a big country with nuclear weapons and an emerging threat to US interests.  On the other hand, it is broadly democratic and a potential South Asian ally.  Apart from the "democratic" part, the same can be said about Pakistan..........  Obviously the US doesn't expect only allies to have weapons.  But when countries that are adversarial to the US gain weapons, they become a threat.

@JamesK, You are self-contradictory. It is a big country with nuclear weapons and an emerging threat to US interests. --- India will inevitably go against US interests. Given that it is a big country, it will not want to stay under the US hegemony. That is why it has BRICS (which is developing alternate currency), does business with Russia, and has 6000 km range ballistic missile. On the other hand, it is broadly democratic and a potential South Asian ally. --- India has always been an US ally. Even during the Cold War, it was a diplomatic protectorate of the USA.

@JamesK, I don't see the US as being particularly protective of India. --- You wrote that in your own comment: it has a long-term quarrel with its neighbor India. I mean, what has the USA got to do with India's quarrel with Pakistan and vice versa?

In the modern world, the USA has no friends, only enemies, so anybody able to attack the USA will attack the USA as soon as the opportunity arises.

@user13964273 "In the modern world, the USA has no friends, only enemies" - the entire Western world would beg to differ on that one.

@F1Krazy They may not agree, but that's how the USA has to see them to feel safe. Even the aforementioned France: if Macron fails to rig the next election, the opposition will highly likely leave NATO but keep its nuclear weapons. That's a threat to the USA. This is also the reason why the USA wants an arms control treaty: to prevent any weapons from being used against them they must control every weapon system in the world.

Pakistan is a country that regularly imprisons its ex leaders (or worse) so clearly its malign influence is an 'emerging' threat to the coming next US leadership.

Nothing wrong with the other answers, they are correct to point out the generic paranoia mindstate that nation states's militaries operate with, dispassionately calculating possible threat vectors.
However, that's not the whole story either.  Pakistan is a bit of a special case, in ways that other countries are not.
Nov 2011, The Pentagon's Secret Plans to Secure Pakistan's Nuclear Arsenal.

Pakistan would be an obvious place for a jihadist organization to seek a nuclear weapon or fissile material: It is the only Muslim-majority state, out of the 50 or so in the world, to have successfully developed nuclear weapons. Its central government has serious trouble controlling the many corners of its territory. Its security services are infiltrated by an unknown number of jihadist sympathizers; a number of jihadist organizations are headquartered there and have relations with the government. And the weapons are stored on bases and in facilities spread across the country -- possibly including one within several miles of Abbottabad, a city that, in addition to having hosted bin Laden, is home to many partisans of the jihadist group Harakat-ul-Mujahideen.


"There are three threats," says Graham Allison, an expert on nuclear weapons who directs the Belfer Center for Science and International Affairs at Harvard. The first is "a terrorist theft of a nuclear weapon, which they take to Mumbai or New York for a nuclear 9/11. The second is a transfer of a nuclear weapon to a state like Iran. The third is a takeover of nuclear weapons by a militant group during a period of instability or splintering of the state."

And that includes other Muslim countries.  Neither Malaysia, nor Indonesia are nuclear, but they are stable enough that, if they were at the same level as Pakistan they would not be as worrying.  Turkey, under Erdogan, might worry folks a bit, but it is still relatively stable.  Pakistan is different, the article is from 2011 but has stability improved much?  And that's without even considering its cuddling up with China.  Or its past history of nuclear technology transfers.
Asides from the risk of a regional nuclear war with India, whenever Pakistan's nukes are talked about, considerations about the stability of the country, and the possibility of a Jihadist takeover are often more talked about than the exact nature of its armaments.

The US does not believe that Pakistan will inevitably use its weapons to attack the USA, nor that the main reason for developing these weapons is an assault on the USA.
You are projecting your preconceived notions onto the quote. You are reading things into it that are not written.

What is a "threat" to the USA?  It doesn't mean that a country will inevitably attack the USA. It only means it might attack the USA.
A threat is an adversary that has the means to attack the US.  France is not normally considered a threat to the US, since it has close relations, it isn't an adversary.  Chad is not a threat to the US, it is poor and has no ability to attack the US.
Pakistan is not like France.  It doesn't have close, friendly relations with the US. It is not like Chad; it has a very capable military including nuclear weapons.  And that capability is growing.
Hence it is an "emerging threat".
But not every threat ends in war.  There is no assumption that Pakistan would  inevitably attack. Only that it might.

From a superpower perspective, all countries, even its allies, are potential rivals. Thus, superpower military doctrines considers any advancement in military technology by other countries as a cause for future concern. After World War 1 and World War 2, the current international "rules-based" order considers the development of weapon technologies "beyond" the security needs of a country as a potential threat to "world peace" as it can lead to an Arms Race.
Thus, here too, it all comes down to the security doctrine envisioned by Pakistani political and military strategists - why does Pakistan need long-range Inter Continental Ballistic Missiles (ICBM)?
Since it became independent, Pakistan has faced a military threat only from its immediate neighbours - India, Iran and Afghanistan. Israel is also considered a country hostile to Pakistan as it has tried to sabotage Pakistan's nuclear and missile programs. India is ofcourse considered its most immediate, and constant, concern as Pakistan has fought 3 wars with it, and is engaged in a proxy war with it.
In case of a war with any of these 4 countries, Pakistan's current assortment of Short Range Ballistic (SRBM) missiles and Medium Range Ballistic (MRBM) missiles are more than sufficient to satisfy their military requirements.

The way ICBMs are used today, having one doesn't offer Pakistan any military advantage against these 4 countries.
Barring the covert US military operation to capture Osama Bin Laden, on Pakistan's territory, Pakistan doesn't have any history of a military conflict with the USA or the west. (Whether even that incident can be considered a "conflict" is debatable as Pakistan has always claimed that it was a joint military operation).
And hence the concern by Pakistan's current and former western allies - what military scenario prompted the need to develop ICBMs that can only be useful to Pakistan in a conflict with other superpowers, and emerging powers, who are far-off from it?
Pakistan hasn't offered any convincing explanation for this.
The recently renewed military alliance between Russia and North Korea, and North Korean troops participating in the Russia-Ukraine war has made the west more wary of the strategic alliances currently being formed by its rivals, Russia and China. Over the last few decades, Pakistan and China have been forming a strategic partnership. The west likely fears that as they court India against China, Pakistan's renewed push to advance its nuclear and missile program may be at the urging of China. In the absence of other convincing rationale from Pakistan, this implies that Pakistan's ICBM is being developed to upgrade Pakistan's military potential against China's major rival - the west.
